# Run 2 different apps simultaneously (appcelerator)

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, simultaneous, app-startup

It's possible to run 2 different apps at the same time on a MacBook Pro?

I need to have one of them with LiveView on iOS Simulator, but another It could be running in the default mode, and I change the files in a text editor like Sublime Text and preview the app in a browser.

I've just one problem, when I run the 2nd app, it uses the same host that the other, then, the 1st one stops (172.0.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I've copied the Appcelerator Studio folder in applications with another name, set a different projects folder and it works fine in WebBrowser, I've just one problem, when I run the 2nd app, it uses the same host that the other, then, the 1st one stops (172.0.0.1)